# Oak Identification Ironwood MI,

Tags: trees, oak, tree-removal

[image: Oak trunk showing damage]

[image: Leaf from the tree]

[[image: Unknown Oak Tree][1]]

I just purchased a house in the Upper Peninsula of Michigan, there's a massive Oak I will need to remove because it's unfortunately leaning over the garage and has severe damage to the trunk.

I have been trying to find a company to harvest it for a few $$ instead of paying a tree service $3k to keep it and make firewood out of it.  The leaves look like either black oak or red Oak, but the bark is very scaly.

Comment: Pictures, location, context; what a great question.  Welcome to the site, Ken!

Comment: I agree that removing a grown tree completely, a careful job that takes planning, is more butchery than surgery, and $500-$600 should be plenty for a 4-hour job. Ladder and 2 long chainsaws from the top down.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  You need to look for Idiots with Chainsaws on YT; you'll then learn why no one should use a ladder when cutting down a tree. Hint: It's a really, really good way to get seriously injured or killed. An arborist I occasionally hire told me that amateurs who want to remove or prune a tree should never let their feet leave the ground - that's why stick-saws exist.

Comment: Silly question, but, are you sure that leaf came from that tree?

Comment: Eonema I'm pretty sure it's from that tree. . The yard is full of them the only other trees close by are pines, unless someone dumped there yard waste before I purchased the house?   It warmed up for a week about 60f the tree started to bid it has Had (5f at night now) little red buds all over it. I'll know for sure when it starts to grow leaves again.

Comment: @YosefBaskin unused to work for a Tree service trimming for a power company. In just to old to deal with This.massive tree.  Even with a Bucket truck and climbing spikes I wouldn't want to deal with it myself. I've seen what can happen even when you know your stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You're right in that it's either a Red or Pin Oak. If it has poor fall color, then it's a pin oak; if reddish for more than a few days, then red oak.

It looks to me like it was one of a pair, with one of them having fallen years ago. The trunk itself looks like it's callusing over the wound, so it unlikely to fall unless the exposed heartwood is rotten.

Have you had a certified arborist look at it from the perspective of "is this tree healthy?" or have you only had tree-cutters look at it from the perspective of "how much to remove?" If you haven't had an arborist look at it, you should, because it may be save-able.

Comment: I have to find one not much available where I am everyone is retired or don't want hard jobs around here   I'm in so many waiting lists for Roofing (6-8 months), A service panel replacement (one year minimum)

Comment: I see your problem. Where I live, you can have an arborist come out just for a consultation (paid, of course); perhaps one of the retirees you mentioned could be convinced to do that, although given you're in the UP travel time could be an issue if you're in a remote location.

Comment: I just searched Google for hours there are no Arborist near me.  The closest city is Duluth Minnesota im littarly at the extreme NW Corner of Michigan about 15 minute drive to Lake Superior nothing in Wisconsin till Minnesota the other  way really nothing,  Milwaukee is about 2-3 hours south then Chicago I don't think anyone would drive up here to look at the tree.  I only moved up here for the a quiet small town. . I'll keep looking, I need to get quotes from other tree services I found 3 so far.

Comment: Wow, I thought it might be difficult to find an arborist, but not THAT difficult, given all of the trees on state and federal forests up there. There's probably no one in a state Natural Resources/Conservation/Forestry Dept who would help either because it's a single tree on private property. Damn.